# What does it means () => css``; in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Hello I'm reading spectrum repo, for learning how they organize their React code, and specifically about styled-components.

In this file [globals/index.js](https://github.com/withspectrum/spectrum/blob/alpha/src/components/globals/index.js) there is this bit of code, I understand what it does, but no why.

```
export const Truncate = () => css`
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 0;
`;
```

It does the [truncate trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/), but how it gets used in a component the Truncate component, how is reused in an actual component.

What it means css``, is styled-components syntax?;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is a way of calling functions in JS, check this out

```js
console.log("hello world".split` `)
```

On their home page you have this example:

```
const Button = styled.a`
  /* This renders the buttons above... Edit me! */
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
  width: 11rem;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;

  /* The GitHub button is a primary button
   * edit this to target it specifically! */
  ${props => props.primary && css`
    background: white;
    color: black;
  `}
`
```

This is just a way of calling the `css` function and passing arguments to it

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is there's nothing special about `styled-components`.

the func`` is a feature of javascript called [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

The use of what the `css` function returns is however a convention of `style-components`

Answer (score 0):

The first paragraph of the styled-components documentation tells us:

> [Utilising tagged template literals](https://styled-components.com/docs) (a recent addition to JavaScript) and the power of CSS, styled-components allows you to write actual CSS code to style your components.

And here's the section for Tagged Templates on the MDN Template String documentation page.

> [Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates). The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string values. The remaining arguments are related to the expressions.

So `css` here is a function that accepts a template string for processing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a function that returns css in the form of a template literal. This is not exclusive to styled components like the others are saying. There are plenty of css packages that use the css prop like emotion. It's just a way of passing css in JS to a component.

```
    const myFuntionalComponent = () => {
      const someCss = () => css`
        color: red;
      `;
      return (
        <div css={someCss()}/>
      )
    }
```